# border on cells of a grid is not uniform in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, react-native

I am trying to build a simple calculator with react native.

I created a button component with borderWidth 0.5 and used this button component to form keypad. But border is not uniform. Border appears thick on few cells compared to others
[image]

Code for this is at
https://github.com/akiran/exponent-calculator/blob/master/components/Buttons.js

https://github.com/akiran/exponent-calculator/blob/master/components/KeyPad.js

Answer (score 1):

I used your code to build an example, could not quite figure out why that is happening. It is however a reproducible issue. Possibly has to do with overlapping borders?

As a workaround, you can use `borderLeftWidth: 1` and `borderTopWidth: 1` and leave the other borders at 0 width, which produces the result visible below.

[image: Uniform borders example]

Comment: But if I use borderRightWidth: 1 and borderBottomWidth: 1,  border is not uniform