# React native flexbox not adapting correctly

Tags: ios, react-native, flexbox

#### Description

I’m developing a react native application with a three-column keyboard. I’ve based the keyboard on a vertical flex layout. Each row in the keyboard is configured with an horizontal flex layout. Buttons and the horizontal and vertical separators are simple views.

On particular conditions it seems that the flex layout cannot correctly size views. 
For instance see the pictures below for iPhone 6 screen size: the three buttons are all equally sized to 123.5 width and a 0.5 blank space is clearly visible between the second and the third column.

[image]

Do you guys have any hypothesis on why does this happen?

#### Reproduction

I’ve put some sample code here: https://rnplay.org/apps/Vl7nVg
In this example however the problem does NOT seem to appear but it uses react v0.31.

Trying to run the sample locally with v0.35 causes the problem.

#### Additional Information

- React Native version: 0.35
- Platform: iOS
- Operating System: MacOS

Comment: Have you confirmed that this issue occurs on a physical device and not just simulator?  Are you zoomed in in simulator ⌘+1 for 100%

Comment: Yes, it happens also on physical device, and the simulator is 100% zoomed

Comment: Possibly related to [border on cells of a grid is not uniform in react native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708618/border-on-cells-of-a-grid-is-not-uniform-in-react-native).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last line verticalLine style from each row.

```
<View style={styles.verticalLine}/>
```

Currently your each row is like this.

```
<View style={styles.row}>
    <View style={styles.verticalLine}/>
    <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>1</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.verticalLine}/>
    <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>2</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.verticalLine}/>
    <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>3</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.verticalLine}/>
</View>
```

After removing it becomes,

```
<View style={styles.row}>
    <View style={styles.verticalLine}/>
    <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>1</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.verticalLine}/>
    <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>2</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.verticalLine}/>
    <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>3</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

This change removed the extra blank space.

Note: 
Not sure why this line was causing an issue. May be some issue with react-native 0.35.0 iOS implementation. Your code worked fine in Android.

Comment: It happens also horizontally. For instance if you take the rnplay sample and run it locally on iphone 5 an horizontal gap appears. It seems like the introduction of fixed size separator views screw up the whole view size computation. I've tested also on previous version (react-native 0.31) and the issue is still present.